# Social icons which are fixed to the centre right side of the browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my social icons to the right side of the browser so that when the browser resizes they always stay following to the right side of the browser, Here is a JSfiddle showing what they currently do http://jsfiddle.net/SHHM8/,

### HTML

```
<div id="fixedsocial">
    <div class="facebookflat"></div>
    <div class="twitterflat"></div> 
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#fixedsocial {
    top:30%;
    height:200px;
    width:60px;
    position:fixed;
}

.facebookflat {
    background:url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
   transition:ease 500ms;
    background-size:50px;
    opacity:1;
}

.facebookflat:hover {
    background:url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-size:60px;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:ease 500ms;
    margin-left:-20px;
    width:70px;

}

.twitterflat {
    background:url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    transition:ease 500ms;
    background-size:50px;
    opacity:1;
}

.twitterflat:hover {
    background:url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-size:60px;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:ease 500ms;
    margin-left:-20px;
    width:70px;
}
```

I have tried to float the container named 'fixedsocial' to the right side of the screen using

```
float:right;
```

however this doesn't do anything.

So please could you make the icons fixed to the center right side of the browser, Thankyou very much for any help

Comment: Please include valid code in the question, not simply a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for tidying this up for me, Ill keep it like this in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `right: 0` to your `#fixedsocial` div then you're done

```
#fixedsocial {
    top:30%;
    height:200px;
    width:60px;
    position:fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHHM8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like:

```
#fixedsocial {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal,

```
margin:30%;
height:200px;
width:60px;
```

Your #fixedsocial will always follow the top of your browser for 30% of your windows.
If you put a fixed margin, your problem will be solved

try

```
margin-top:150px;
height:200px;
width:60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something along the lines off:

```css
.sidebar-wrap{
    position: fixed;    
    width: 60px;
    height:250px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -125px; /* Needs to be half of the height */
}
```

See this article for more information: [Responsive Sticky Social Sidebar](http://jacobonthenet.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/responsive-sticky-social-sidebar-tutorial.html)